# Will `list.extend()` always operate one-by-one?

Tags: python

I came up with a one-liner for factorials as

```py
factorial = [n:=(1 if i==0 else n*i) for i in range(10)]
```

Now I'm thinking about a two-liner

```py
factorial = [1]
factorial.extend(factorial[-1]*i for i in range(1, 10))
```

It works on my Python 3.8 interpreter, but obviously this implementation depends on `list.extend()` operating in a one-by-one fashion. It will not work say, if `list.extend()` changes its implementation to adding things in batch.

Is there any specification dictating this behavior on `list.extend`?

Comment: Your code works as you expect, because you extend from a generator which yields one element at a time.  Note that the behaviour is different with `factorial.extend([factorial[-1]*i for i in range(1, 10)])` where the argument of `.extend` is a list rather than a generator.

Comment: FWIW: if you need to ask this question, don't write code like this…

Comment: Your one-liner would be faster if you did ```if not i``` instead of ```if i == 0```

Comment: @slothrop The question is whether `list.extend` *internally* does something like turning the generator into a list before actually adding its elements to the list in one go…

Comment: @deceze Ah yes, that's true.  In fact, the Python docs say that `list.extend()` is "equivalent to `a[len(a):] = iterable`" - but in this case the implementation does not seem to be equivalent.  `factorial[1:] = (factorial[-1]*i for i in range(1, 10))` gives the "wrong" result, i.e. the same as extending from a list comprehension, and not the same as extending from a generator.

Comment: @deceze To be on the safe side, probably yes. But I think there can be cases that this expression (if `list.extend()` always does things one-by-one) is useful. For example, generating Fibonacci numbers, in which we'll need to refer to `fib[-1]` and `fib[-2]`.